# Flutter: Refresh image after add

Tags: flutter, crud

If I have added data to the flutter in firebase, but I want to add more, the image on the added page still appears before the image, how do I refresh it to return to blank as before?

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String format = DateFormat('dd:mm:yy').format(now);
    var fullImageName = 'foto-$format' + '.jpg';
    var fullImageName2 = 'foto-$format' + '.jpg';

    final StorageReference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fullImageName);
    final StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(image);

    // Wait upload task to complete
    final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = 
    (await task.onComplete);
    // Get image uRL
    final String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());

    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      DocumentReference ref = await db
          .collection('resep')
          .add({'nama': '$nama', 'resep': '$resep', 'image': '$url', 'email' : widget.email});
      setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
      Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Say above code you have written is in Page2 which is navigated from Page1.

So when you upload the image on firebase storage and pop the page2. Then you can refresh the page as following,

When you push a new page2 from page1 you can have its pop callback.

```
// To check if you got your callback or not just pass bool data type with MaterialPageRoute
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<bool>(builder: (context) => page2()),).then((bool res) {
      // check here if you got your callback data or not
      if(res!=null && res==true){
         // fetch your updated content here
      }
    });
```

When you pop your page2 then,

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

Comment: what is the content in refreshpage sir?

Comment: refreshPage() will be your code to fetch the and load the data again.

Comment: Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPage());
          Navigator.push(context, route);




this my code from p1 to p2

Comment: Then change your push syntax like, Navigator.push(context, route).then((val){
      refreshPage();
    });

Comment: refreshpage is error, because there is no content, I'm confused with the contents or methods that are in it

Comment: Refresh page is not a method. I was just telling you that you can refresh or update your content here using your own logic.